# Deploying client and server nodejs apps to Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

I set up my project with two apps in the root directory initially, one for the client and one for the server. My directory looks like this:

```
+--root
   |--client
   |    |--node_modules
   |    |--package.json
   |
   |--server
        |--node_modules
        |--package.json
```

I would run npm start in each directory respectively to start the client code, which had the code for the React components and Routes and the server code for the REST api.

I'm now trying to deploy my project on Azure and I can't get it to work now like the tutorials suggest I should. I reorganized my package structure to look use one package.json now, but I still run into the problem that I need to run two applications after deploying to Azure in order for my website to function. This is what my directory looks like now and I'm using concurrently to run my custom commands, `npm run client` and `npm run server`.

```
+--root
   |--client
   |--server
   |--node_modules
   |--package.json
```

Yet I still cannot get my site to run. Is it because there is no index.html at the wwwroot after it is deployed? How should I fix my project in order to host it on Azure?

Comment: Presumably you have some sort of error?.... however, I’m going to presume you’ve fell foul of the limitation on Azure where you can’t run from a sub folder.

Comment: What would be the best way to get my project hosted? Should I make two separate apps in Azure?

Comment: You don’t need to “host” your client app, this will run in the browser. You only need to host your server app and have it serve up your client app.

Comment: I think I do, because I have routing logic on the client side as well.

Comment: When you say "routing logic" - what do you mean? My presumption is given you've mentioned this is a React app that this is an SPA your building, as such the server app only needs to serve the client app and then any routing you would handle on the client (e.g. via [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)). At the minute I can only assume to know what your "client" app is, if it is infact also a Node app then yes you would need to host it on Azure too...but the name is misleading if that is the case.

Comment: To be a little more specific, the "server" side app is another nodejs project which serves up the API that my website uses. The client is another nodejs application which routes different views using React Router. EDIT: The client was created using create-react-app.

Comment: Right got you, that now makes more sense, however, therein lies your problem. Your deployment approach is flawed IMO, you're trying to run multiple apps (Node instances) under a single app which means you completely lose the benefits of using a PaaS like Azure on one of those instances. There are a number of reasons why you really ought to be deploying these as *separate* apps...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to host my server side code by setting up a new nodejs project in Azure and then copying over my server code into that project. Now my API is hosted on Azure. I then deployed my client code to heroku. This worked like a charm, it detected the package.json and automatically ran the `npm start` script which started the client and read the webconfig to know to use the src/index.js as the starting point for my app. I presume it also started my server code as well, since my `npm start` command runs the `npm run server` command also via concurrently but it doesn't look like the client is able to reach the API via the local host url I was using. I think this is a separate issue I need to look into.